# Make text not selectable when printing to PDF

Tags: cocoa, pdf

I have a view designed for printing which includes a watermark, a transparent view which draws some text atop the other content.

When printing and using the Mac OS **Save as PDF** feature, the watermark text is selectable. Sometimes this interferes with selecting the other content, other times it's just distracting.

How can I make the text not selectable in the generated PDF?

I tried drawing the watermark behind the other content instead of in front. It didn't prevent selecting the watermark, but kept it out of the way of the other content. However, the table view rows occluded the watermark, which of course is worse.

---

Commenter asked for code, so here's some code which prepares the view:

```
// self.view is the print view
// watermark is an instance of WatermarkBackground, an NSView
if (watermark) {
    watermark.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:watermark positioned:NSWindowAbove relativeTo:nil];
}
```

And the line in [WatermarkBackground drawRect] which does the drawing:

```
// _message is an NSString
// textAttributes returns a dictionary with a color and font
[_message drawWithRect:textRect
               options:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping
            attributes:[WatermarkBackground textAttributes]];
```

---

I meant to post this screenshot originally:

[image]

Comment: show us some code that you are using.. start with that much first\

Comment: I'm not sure what part of the code could be helpful to see, but posted the two most relevant bits.

Comment: I would use an image with a transparent background for your watermark.  Very simple and accomplishes your goal.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to create one or multiple `CGPath`s from your string and draw those into the PDF instead. One way to do so would be to use `CTFontCreatePathForGlyph`, but it's actually quite a lot of work to do this for entire strings, Core Text does help, but it's a pretty low-level framework.

If you're always drawing the same watermark, it would be much easier to create a static PDF in some vector graphics app and use that with `CGPDFPageDraw` etc. Illustrator has a "Convert to Paths" command for text objects.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there in no way to make text unselectable in PDF. <strike>Probably the best solution would be to use an image watermark instead.</strike>

However, if it is in front of text, it can make background text difficult to select. If it is behind everything, there will be same issues with obscuring it with tables. So, possibly a better plan of action would be not to try to make text unselectable, but rather make table background transparent. Then, use image watermark.

Taking an idea from omz, instead of using CGPaths and generating them on the fly, the simplest, most elegant solution would be this:

1. Create a vector watermark by typing the text in a vector editor and expanding text to create outlines.
2. Save it as SVG or PDF.
3. Then, put this new vector graphic on top as a watermark. It will not be selectable, will not obscure the view, and will not be obscured by tables.

Comment: Thanks. If there's no way to make the text unselectable, using an image makes sense. But since I'm using alternating row colors I don't see how I could make the table background transparent. (I posted a screenshot.)

Comment: Hm. With that in mind, I think omz's answer is on the right track. I'll edit my answer to explain new idea.

Comment: @Jonas Your statement is not accurate, there are ways of doing this, several ways actually. In a worst case scenario, you can paint your text using normal drawing operations (lines and curves) and it will not be selectable. omz's answer is the way to go though